# componentHandler.upgradeDom() in material-design-lite with for loop

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I am using material design lite and inserting elements with for loop.

```
var insertClass ='';
var classlist = document.querySelector('.classList');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    insertClass += '<div class="eachClass">' +
                      '<p>'+ i +'</p>' +
                     '<button id="demo-menu-lower-right" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">'+
                       '<i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>'+
                     '</button>' +
                     '<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-right">' +
                       '<li class="mdl-menu__item deleteClass">Delete</li>' +
                       '<li class="mdl-menu__item editClass">Edit</li>' +
                     '</ul>' +
                  '</div>';
}
classlist.innerHTML = insertClass;
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered('MaterialMenu', 'mdl-js-menu');
```

The `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` function is not working at all,
but when I use `upgradeDom()` it will work only on first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have provided, you are going to end up with multiple buttons with the same **id** and multiple ul menus with the same **for**. That would potentially explain why you appear to only get one menu as the **id** and **for** are used by material design lite to bind the buttons and menus together. Try rewriting your example with:

```
'<button id="demo-menu-lower-right_' + i + '" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">'+
   '<i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>'+
'</button>' +
'<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-right_' + i + '">' +
   '<li class="mdl-menu__item deleteClass">Delete</li>' +
   '<li class="mdl-menu__item editClass">Edit</li>' +
 '</ul>'
```

...which will give each button and menu a unique id or for.